# How do I send a patch with an accompanying message to the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, email

So I found a bug, fixed it, and want to send the patch for it.

I followed the [Write and submit your first Linux kernel patch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLBrBBImJt4) youtube video, set up git-email, formatted everything, etc., and want to send it.

My issue: I don't want to send it alone but with an accompanying message and sample userspace code that gets fixed by the patch. Both seem ill-suited for the commit message.

Do I send that via a separate email? Should that need to be somehow specially formatted
too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you extract your commit, add `--cover-letter` to the `git format-patch` options. This will extract your commit with a `0001` prefix, and create a cover letter template with a `0000` prefix. You can edit that to contain your accompanying message and sample code, then send both with a single `git send-email` invocation: your cover letter will be sent first, with your actual patch in reply to it.